# How to change layout elements when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android

I would like to change the layout elements when the soft-keyboard activated, as below:

Before keyboard appears:
[image: Before keyboard appears]

After keyboard appears
[image: After keyboard appears]

Here's the question with clearer picture of what I want.

**Requirements:**

- Noticed that the "Forgot Password" view gone and "Facebook image" and "Create New Facebook Account" views are completely changed. How can we implement a layout like this.
- No scroll view is involved.
- The layout should work on phone with any screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library:

https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent

Listen to the keyboard visibility and change your layout manually